# Output the number located in number series

Tags: c

Given a sequence formed from natural numbers from 1 to 99,
each of which is repeated a number of times equal to the value of this
numbers: 122333444455555.... Determine and specify the number that will be located at the P-th (1 < P > 2500 - specified by the user) position in this sequence.

I wrote code that outputs a sequence of numbers from 1 to 99 with repetition. But I had a problem with the output of the number located at the position specified by the user. Also, according to the task, I cannot use an array

My code without the output of the number located at the position specified by the user

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    system("chcp 1251");
    printf("\n");
    const int Num_Max = 99;
    int P, number = 0;
    printf("Series of number: ");
    for (int i = 0; i <= Num_Max; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            printf("%d", number);
        }
        number++;
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Enter the position: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &P);
    if (P >= 1 && P <= 2500)
    {
        printf("Chosen position: %d\n", P);
    }
    else
    {
        while (P < 1 || P > 2500)
        {
            printf("Another number: ");
            scanf_s("%d", &P);
        }
        printf("Chosen position: %d\n", P);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should find out the position you're supposed to look for *before* computing the sequence. Then just compute it while keeping track of how many digits into it you are, but only actually print out that particular value.

Comment: It is rather mathematical question

Comment: @Shawn yuo do not need to compute the sequence

Comment: @0___________ I'm sure there's some equation that can replace a brute force approach, but baby steps first.

Comment: @Shawn the equation is in my answer

Answer (score 1):

For these small numbers it should work:

```
unsigned int_sqrt(unsigned s)
{
    unsigned int x0 = s / 2;
    unsigned x1 = ( x0 + s / x0 ) / 2;

    while( x1 < x0 )
    {
        x0 = x1;
        x1 = ( x0 + s / x0 ) / 2;
    }       
    return x0;
}


int atPosition(unsigned pos)
{
    unsigned delta = 1 + 8.0 * pos;
    unsigned sqrtdelta = int_sqrt(delta);
    int res = (-1 + sqrtdelta)/2 + !!(delta - sqrtdelta * sqrtdelta);

    
    return res;
}
```

```
int atPosition(unsigned pos)
{
    double dres = (-1 + sqrt(1 + 8.0 * pos))/2;
    int res = (int)dres + ((dres - (int)dres) != 0);
    
    return res;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/5zeejjoce